# Concurrency in real-time system

Tags: concurrency, real-time

Please shed some light on me.

How real-time system defines that events happened simultaneously?
1. By the time they occurred?
2. By the time range they occurred?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It probably depends on the problem at hand. What's your problem you're trying to solve? Why do you need to detect simultaneity of events?

Comment: Just be interesting at it. Suppose two events have been received in the same time,but because the processor is only able to process events in sequential, the final result might completely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look on [Operational Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation) algorithms, they deal  perfectly with concurrent events with continuous integration.

An OT enabled system is able to accept time-concurrent events and transform these events, if necessary, so State in server and all clients Converge.

Or to say in other way is able to manage client "divergence" due network latency and make all client and server to finish in same state with  "operations" applied in a well-defined order.

Google Wave was an example of a system using OT for Concurrent Editing, [here](http://wave-protocol.googlecode.com/hg/whitepapers/operational-transform/operational-transform.html) you can see a rude explanation on how Google Wave deal with OT. and [here](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/understanding-and-applying-operational-transformation) you have a very well develop explanation.